# Filezilla- EC2 - FTP Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, filezilla

I  have a windows EC2 instance and I have my local machine. Now I am running the Filezilla FTP server in the EC2 instance. I try to FTP into the cloud FTP server and I get the following.

[image: The Error -- >]

I have allowed port 21, 22 for incoming. The instance is Windows 2008 R2. Any ideas?

Edit 1 - I am using the passive configuration on Filezilla server :

[image]

Still the result is the same.

Comment: Since everything in AWS is NAT'd, you need to use a passive configuration for your FTP server.

Comment: You dont want a port range that large, should only be a hundred ports or so above 1024. (Needs to be open in sec group). The ip address has to be the public IP, not internal ip.

Comment: @datasage - it is the public ip and I changed that to 100 difference for the ports. It still shows the same thing ?

Comment: Are you connecting to the private ip? 10.x.x.x? That wont work from your local machine.